# In a function how to reference one or more functions by either the fn.name (as a string) or the fn.obj?

Tags: r, function, eval, dry

Sometimes in R a function wants a string or sometimes it wants an object.

For example, `rm(x);` and `rm("x");` work the same.

**NOTE**: In this example `x` or `"x"` is **NOT** a function.  I generically call it an **OBJECT**.  In the example below, I am referring to functions as **FN.STR** or **FN.OBJ**, but the QUESTION is looking for a general OBJECT MANIPULATOR.  Given a thing, determine if it is a string or object, and return a string/object as requested by the Function.  A function then serves as a general API to access R objects.

```
> rm
function (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos), 
    inherits = FALSE) 
{
    dots <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
    if (length(dots) && !all(vapply(dots, function(x) is.symbol(x) || 
        is.character(x), NA, USE.NAMES = FALSE))) 
        stop("... must contain names or character strings")
    names <- vapply(dots, as.character, "")
    if (length(names) == 0L) 
        names <- character()
    list <- .Primitive("c")(list, names)
    .Internal(remove(list, envir, inherits))
}
<bytecode: 0x00000136a0f22d80>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

This is useful on this function because the USER doesn't have to remember: do I need the string or object.  In fact, you can mix:  `x=1; y=2; rm(x,"y");`  The `...` dots have been expended to make this happen... Ideally, it would be nice to save the `...` dots for passing parameters through to other functions or for lazy loading like `sum` allows:  `sum(1,2,3) == sum(c(1,2,3))`.  [Or maybe `..1` could be reimagined to allow for multiple dots: `...a`, `...b`, {ldots}, `...z` where the name/order of the `...{letter}` would allow lots of `match.call` magic.  Regardless, even this magic is happening in the function, not as a standalone VARIADIC external `magicFunction`]

### Objective

Anyway, I am trying to write a few variadic functions that allow the USER to input either the FUN as `fn.str` or as `fn.obj`.  At the GLOBAL scope, the following will work:

```
str.fromObjectName = function(objname) 
    { 
    res = deparse(substitute(objname));
    res = str.replace('"', "", res);
    return(res);
    }
```

WHERE `str.replace` is a extension of gsub, so for simplicity, let's say:

```
str.replace = function(search, replace, str)
    {
    gsub(search, replace, str, fixed=TRUE);
    }
```

So if it is an object, I get the string.name of it (whether or not it actually exists, no error thrown).  If it is a string, it has an extra `"` wrapping it, so the `str.replace` takes care of that.

As a procedural function, I would like to be able to access this in OTHER functions.  But with the nature of the R stack (or my lack of understanding), I can't seem to get it to work.  I found a solution in some `baseR` code that I have applied to use the `...` dots to TRAP the potential object.  But it has some limitations:  I have to use the `...` dots so I can't use them for other purposes, and if I call a function from a function the evaluation of the original function name gets lost, so I apply the `character.only=FALSE` when I call the function INTERNALLY to the other function where at some point the FN.OBJ was converted to FN.STR

So if I review the base packages with `character.only` I believe the `help` or `library` uses it to trap the pkg as a string or object.  Maybe the solution is trivial which I am missing, but as I review the `base` code, it seems like it may be a challenge.  It appears the function doesn't know what to do automatically without the `character.only` flag.

```
> library
function (package, help, pos = 2, lib.loc = NULL, character.only = FALSE, 
    
    ...
    
    
        if (!character.only) 
            package <- as.character(substitute(package))
        
        
    ...

    
    else if (!missing(help)) {
        if (!character.only) 
            help <- as.character(substitute(help))
        
    
    ...
    
        
    else invisible(.packages())
}
<bytecode: 0x0000013699060b10>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

### An example

Here is a preamble of one function:

```
function.info = function(..., character.only=FALSE)
    {
    if(character.only) 
        { 
        fn.str = unlist(list(...)); 
        } else {
                fn.str = str.fromObjectName(...);
                }
    }
```

NOTE: the `...` passthrough allows the GLOBAL function to correctly scope.

This allows the function str `"sum"` or the function object `sum` to be inputed into the function (making life BETTER for the user).  In the spirit of DRY and VARIADIC programming, it would be nice if I could do this as one external function to `function.info` ... and allow multiple fn objects to be passed in as parameters that are either the str `"sum"` or the object `sum` which INTERNALLY for most purposes I just want the resulting str.

### Question

Given a function, how to allow a user to pass multiple `FUN` elements as either obj/string (mix allowed) using an external function (DRY = don't repeat yourself).  **In the example, I am referring to FUN.OBJ**, but the goal would be to return anything that could be called an OBJ in R, **not just a function**.

```
magicFunction = function(FUN.OBJ.OR.STR, return="STR")
    {
    # do something here ... FUN.OBJ could be any R.OBJ
    FUN.AS.STR;
    # or if return = "OBJ"
    FUN.AS.OBJ
    }

v.math = function(data=c("#abcdef","#123456"), FUN, param="hi", FUN.pre="hex2dec", FUN.post=dec2hex)
    {
    # takes input [whether a str/obj] and returns a string/object.
    fn.str = magicFunction(FUN);
    fn.pre = magicFunction(FUN.pre);
    fn.post = magicFunction(FUN.post);

    # get to the main event 
    }
```

In the above, `"hex2dec"` is a string (as in `"foo"`) and `dec2hex` is an object (as in `bar`): both referring to functions [something akin to `match.fun(base::sum)` or `match.fun("base::sum")`; I think currently it only searches the TOP of the stack.].  I can call my function `str.fromObjectName` on them in the GLOBAL sphere and get what I want, but when placed inside another function, it will return something else.  I did a bunch of sys.call VOODOO that I didn't understand fully, and it would allow it to work at one-level deep of function calls (I guess because of the nature of the call stack).  And it would only work on have one FUN to evaluate in the `v.math` where I have **3** functions to evaluate.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to recreate the `match.fun()` function; here `magicFunction` is `match.fun`. But relying on this auto detection can lead to confusing behavior. For example, if you you do `x <- "a"; rm(x)` what should be removed, `x` or `a`? It basically prevents you from passing variables for values to your function without doing something crazy. Functions like `rm` often have a separate parameter like `list=` where you can use string variables. So you'll want to include some sort of fallback as well.

Comment: @MrFlick USER inputs a string/object.  I need to detect it, and return what my INTERNALS need a string or object.  If I have placed them variadically, I want to reference the TOP of the stack, in your example `x`.  What is the PARENT name, in this case `x`.

Comment: `match.fun` from my understanding only works on the LOADED namespace and only returns the TOP object that is a function.  In my use case, the object could be a list or a dataframe or a function, and so on (e.g., a generic object).  This is why they are called `VARIADIC` functions.

Comment: ```> match.fun("base::sum")
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'base::sum' of mode 'function' was not found
```  Notice `match.fun` only returns based on the STACK, not searching in a particular NAMESPACE ... if I have conflicting names (mask), it would be nice to get the `function.info` for a particular function as in `base::sum` or `packageName:::sum` ... My function `function.info` TRAPS the `match.fun` errors, but ultimately I still haven't figured out how to return a particular fun `packageName::sum` if a conflicting function is attached.

Comment: *"In my use case, the object could be a list or a dataframe or a function, and so on"*. I think 2 or 3 concrete examples with desired behavior would go a lot further than your multiple paragraphs of explanations. I have no idea what you would want to happen if the user passed in a data frame. And I don't understand why `match.fun` doesn't work for you. Can you please show an example of both?

Comment: Do note that `match.fun(sum)`, `match.fun("sum")`, `match.fun(base::sum)` all work nicely. So maybe what you want is a minor adjustment to `match.fun` to handle the edge-case where `::` is used in a string? Though I still have no idea what a `list` or `data.frame` has to do with anything.

Comment: @GregorThomas I want a `magicFuntion` that has one INPUT.  That could be an "object" or a "string".  I need to detect what it is.  I then need to return either an "object" or a "string".  Use cases?  `match.fun(base::sum)` works but `match.fun("base::sum")` fails.  `install.packages("bit")` works but `install.packages(bit)` fails.

Comment: And, `match.fun` is nice so that if a user has defined `sum <- 5` in the global environment, `match.fun("sum")` will return the function, not the numeric vector.

Comment: Okay, so reiterating the second sentence of my comment, it sounds like you want you a minor adjustment to `match.fun` to handle the edge-case where `::` is used in a string.

Comment: Note that `base::sum` is not really a function. It's an expression that returns a function. The `::` is a function. So you're really calling `\`::\`(base, sum)` which needs to be evaluated before it will work.  Just like `foo <- function(x) function(z) z+x; foo(2)(3)`. So is that really the only exceptional case you want to handle?

Comment: @GregorThomas Sure, that solves the `function` object issue.  But what about the generic object issue.  That is what VARIADIC means.  `library("bit")` works and `library(bit)` works.  So I can write a function that passes a string `pkg = "bit";` and call `library(pkg)`, it doesn't work.  ARGH?  It wants an object `pkg` not a string.

Comment: Maybe "variadic" means something different to you. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) it just means that the function accepts any number of arguments. It does not necessarily mean the same function can accept different data types. That sounds more like "polymorphism"

Comment: Variadic in the mathematical (or statistical) sense:  it varies.  That is why FUNCTIONS even exist to make things solveable in a variable way.  I like your polymorphism idea, a new word for today.  I guess when I say variadic, I mean extensible.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility

Comment: I'd also like to frame-challenge *"This allows the function str "sum" or the function object sum to be inputed into the function (making life BETTER for the user)"*. This is not necessarily better for the user. Often, a single correct way to do things is easier/better than flexibility--if the flexibility isn't universal (and as you've gone at length to point out, it is far from universal in R) it can cause confusion, when, for example, a vector, a function, and a column in a data frame all share a name.

Comment: @GregorThomas This is SO.  I asked a question on writing a function that inputs a string/object and returns a string/object, SMARTLY. That is the ask.  We can theorize on what is best for the user.  R is a loosely scripted language meaning `df` could be a dataframe, or a list, or a function, or a X ... because it is loosely scripted I need extensible API-like functions that allow me to input a str/obj and return a str/obj.  I am struggling to understand why this ASK is so challenging to understand.   Functions are simple, inputs/outputs.  I have given some SPECS, hence the question on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a wrapper around `match.fun` to allow for the user to include `::` in a string argument:

```
as_fun = function(x) {
  if(is.character(x) && grepl("::", x)) return(eval(parse(text = x)))
  match.fun(x)
}

as_fun(base::sum)
# function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
as_fun("base::sum")
# function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
as_fun(sum)
# function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
as_fun("sum")
# function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

Comment: This is a nice fix to the `match.fun` bug.  Now do `library(pkg)` WHERE `pkg="stringi"` ... In this case, I need to convert the string `pkg` to an object before I pass it into library (if I am doing this procedurally inside a function)

Comment: `mshaffers_libarary = \(x) {
  x = as.character(substitute(x));
  library(x, character.only = TRUE)
}`

Comment: At some point, code needs to convert to a particular type of object to behave correctly. In some cases R functions are more or less flexible. In the cases where they are less flexible, you can certainly write your own wrappers. But the flexibility is sensitive--it can be difficult and it can cause bugs. If it were easy, it would already be done by default.  If you want to take on that work to add flexibility for your users, that's a choice your making, but don't get too FRUSTRATED when it isn't straightforward.

Comment: If I had a generic function, I could then know.  Okay, I have `pkg`="stringi" and want to call library, so I need a wrapper.  You want a wrapper for `library` and another wrapper for `match.fun`.  How about a generic wrapper.  DRY = don't repeat yourself.  The need for a general function.  How about `exists("objstr")`?  In that case, if I have an object, I have to get its string.

Comment: What if `function2` has a string `pkg = "stringi";` and calls `mshaffers_libarary`.  Will it not substitute to (`pkg`) not `stringi`, so again I am stuck.

Comment: Yeah, and if you have `dplyr <- "stringi"` and `function2` calls `mshaffers_library(dplyr)`--which package do you even want to load?

Comment: You are speaking hypotheticals.  I am talking specifics.  There is no package called `pkg` but a user may write a function with a different variable name (symbol).  I have hacked a solution that worked at one level deep with S+ logic on do-call systm call VOODOO that I don't understand.  It would work if I knew the name of the variable as 'pkg' at one-level of function depth.

Comment: `is.character(x)` can fail easily.  I have had to TRAP errors using around TRYING the `typeof(x)` ... this is how I can get a sense for what type of object it is.

Comment: Thank you Gregor.  I am asking the question because I think it is difficult.  I am not an R-VOODO-NINJA, I am just a PROCEDURAL-TYPE, so I wanted to understand that INDEED it is difficult.  From a developer perspective, it would be nice to have a generic API to make R more extensible.  `exists` vs. `library` vs `rm` vs `match.fun` vs ON and ON.  It would be nice if they could be wrapped so they just work.  A common feature of a scripting language is to be able to check if something exists before an error is thrown.  `is.null(NONEXISTENTOBJECT)` vs. `exists(NONEXISTENTOBJECT.as.STRING)`